# Always Hot after 3-way? Seemingly Simple Home Circuit Wiring Solution but Stumped

Tags: electrical

Trying to get an always hot black (or red) after a 3 way switch from where power enters the box/circuit. Need to maintain the 3-way switch functionality in box 1 and 2. Can't really add any additional wire because the routes are too tight/too many bends.

TLDR: How can I get a constant hot from Box 1 (left) to Box 2 (right) with a 3-way switch as the fixture between source and Box 2?

I added a picture to help illustrate the layout and goal. Can add more or less any switches that help facilitate the goal - like a Lutron remote switch, but would prefer not to if there's some solution here

Thank you :-)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that with dumb 3-way switches the way to do this is with 4 wires:

- Always Hot
- Two Travelers
- Neutral

but you only have 3 wires. So the solution is to find *smart* switches that communicate via radio or power-line signalling or something so that you only need one traveler. Or possibly *no travelers at all*. The end result being either:

- Smart switch, single traveler in box 1
- Always Hot/Neutral/Traveler between box 1 and box 2
- Smart switch, single traveler in box 2

I am having trouble finding an example of this type. I have seen some, but at the moment everything I can find either requires both travelers or uses some sort of wireless control.

or

- Remote Switch, box 1
- Always Hot/Neutral/extra wire between box 1 and box 2
- Smart switch in box 2

Example: Lutron Caseta with Pico remote

Comment: How bad of an idea would it be to tie the red and black in Box 2 (not source) to create an always hot? I don't think it'd be dangerous since current is only going through Black OR Red at any given point but it would cause a flicker in the rest of the circuit when flipped.

Comment: You can do that. But if you do that then your 3-way switched light fixture will always be on, except for a split second when you flip a switch. So if you're going to do that, might as well just remove Switch 2 and make one wire always hot and the other switched hot, or remove switch 1, make one wire always hot and the other wire becomes extra.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the problem. This is what a 3-way switch schematic looks like. Black = always-hot.  The travelers operate as "one is hot, one is not".

[image]

The /3 cable between switches, as you can plainly see, is fully subscribed.  It has no spare wires.  There is no wire on which to place an always-hot. So your goal is not going to happen in a traditional switch regime.

However, to paint an illustration on what manassehkatz is talking about, here's my diagram rearranged as smart switches.

[image]

I realize you don't give a toot about smart switches, but note closely how the topology change brings both always-hot and neutral to the right switch.

Note that you almost never get a choice about where the smart-switch master must be, so if you want the full feature-set at the other location, choose a smart switch family which provides that. We're normally recommending smart switches which use radio or powerline-coded signaling to communicate, because there often isn't a spare wire for datacomm.

However you have one here, usable for datacomm OR switched-hot. So you have a wider choice of smart switches, or can put the smart switch master in the left and use the spare wire for switched-hot.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it's under construction. Whoever did your wiring apparently forgot to put a 14/2 for constant power to the right box. The ideal solution would be to have the wiring fixed to include the constant power supply there. It's always possible to get a wire through - electricians have many techniques and will always win the path challenge.

It's not possible to get a constant hot at the right side while also preserving the three-way switch function and only using the one 14/3 cable between the two boxes. The normal way to do this is to feed power in to the box using a 14/2 for the constant power feed. Nowadays you do have an available option however: remote and smart switches. You could change to using the 14/3 for constant power only, abandoning and capping off the third wire. Install a switch in the right box and a remote of some kind at the left location.

Comment: Yeah, the issue is the wiring on this circuit was never correct and I actually pulled the 14-3 to replace 14-2 that was causing switch pattern issues and using white as the traveler. I was thinking of tying the blacks in Box 1 but didn't fully think through the 3-way setup. The wire is through LVL and headers that are VERY hard to drill through/access without really tearing into the ceiling. Have you seen any Smart toggle switches by chance? I'm pretty familiar with Lutron and typical Home Depot stuff and haven't come across any.

Comment: Lutron makes the Pico remote that works with some of their switches. It's a small battery remote that installs like a pushbutton switch, and you can use it in the left location in place of a three way switch. It even installs in a Decora box so that it looks like a switch.